# Desktop application encryption vs Web app with client-side encryption

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, cryptography, desktop-application

I need to make a solution that uses a server for authentication/access control and encryption on client-side.

The first option is to make a java/fx desktop app that communicate with the server and takes care of encryption.

The second option is to make a web application with client-side javascript cryptography

Notes:

- Using hybrid crypto, asymmetric keys are already generated for users, so only the symmetric key will be generated using java/js
- HTTPS will be used

So which approach is more secure/efficient ? And is there any changes i should make to better the solution ?

Comment: The issue with both solutions is that you need to trust the code somehow. This can be easier to accomplish on a client side app sometimes, as it is downloaded only once (with updates build in or provided by a repo), and you can have additional controls like signed downloads and / or trusted software repositories. Currently the JS has access to random number generators by the OS, so in that sense there may not be that much of a difference, especially if you trust the TLS connection enough - making sure that you're connected to the right server.

Comment: Currently you will be hard pressed to *make* your clients install Java SE, especially since they may not even be able to. Java SE has lost the game for desktop applications, in my opinion. Which is a shame because it is in many ways better than e.g. .NET and / or native C++. Still, the perceived insecurity, the annoying update mechanism, the bad UI and everything else has quite killed it dead. For a *generic* user application, don't go there (and note I'm quite the Java evangelist, so this critique doesn't come natural to me).

Comment: Alright, so it comes down to personal preference if it's no difference. i don't know about experts' opinions but I'm fan of java myself, For UI, javaFX gives great results and i have no problem installing java SE and so since this is part of a personal project kinda. 
Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Java will probably be faster and better when it comes to support HW acceleration. You *may* also be better protected against side channel attacks, although that is hard to quantify.